# Teradata filter query to pull all data for a month

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a query below which fetches me the data for last day of a month. In this query, ME_DT is defined as date time type. So when I do the max on ME_DT then it gives me the data for last day of a month. I think I need to convert the date time type to integer YYYYMM in a teradata filter condition, so that it gives me the data for the entire month not just for the last day of a month. How should I modify my existing query to get my desired result?

```
PADW.PL_CURR_DEFN_LOSS_FRCST_ME.ME_DT = 
(select max (PADW.PL_CURR_DEFN_LOSS_FRCST_ME.ME_DT) from PADW.PL_CURR_DEFN_LOSS_FRCST_ME)
```

Comment: If this is Teradata, you can change the tag from `mysql` + `sql-server` to `teradata`, and add plain `sql` tag. I started to change for you but since you are actively editing I cancelled. Also the title could be more specific to what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid calculations on a column in the WHERE-condition to get better estimates and possible index/partition-access:

```
with cte (dt) as
(
select max (PADW.PL_CURR_DEFN_LOSS_FRCST_ME.ME_DT) 
from PADW.PL_CURR_DEFN_LOSS_FRCST_ME
)

select ....
where PADW.PL_CURR_DEFN_LOSS_FRCST_ME.ME_DT 
between TRUNC(dt, 'mon')
    and last_day(dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to use filer on the table because it has millions of records...

i did this ...but still verifying if I have got what i want...

```
(PADW.PL_CURR_DEFN_LOSS_FRCST_ME.ME_DT = 
(select max (cast(PADW.PL_CURR_DEFN_LOSS_FRCST_ME.ME_DT as date format 'YYYYMM')) from PADW.PL_CURR_DEFN_LOSS_FRCST_ME))
```